# Padding is odd in the "Looking for your Teams" in the hamburger menu

Tags: bug, design, 404-not-found, stack-overflow-for-teams

There should likely be a bit of padding on the left side there

[image]

Every other item in that menu has padding, so that item should likely have padding too.

Possibly related (although only tested on SO, not MSE), but the Warning icon for Page not found on SO also lacks padding, but on the top:

[image]

Can the padding be put back, please?

Comment: FWIW, the padding matches the other top-level items in the `nav-links` list, like PUBLIC and TEAMS. I guess the issue is that it's a top-level item instead of being inside an indented sublist under "Teams", like how "Questions" is in an indented sublist under "Public. But on wider screens that have a static sidebar instead of the hamburger menu, there [isn't much room in the sidebar](https://i.imgur.com/tXU1ANg.png) to accommodate indenting it.